# Winding number and homotopy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology

Given two maps $f,g : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, I want to show that if they have the same winding number, then there is a homotopy between them.

Well, we know that we can write them as $f(\exp(2 \pi i t))= f(1) \exp(2 \pi i \phi_f(t))$ and $g(\exp(2 \pi i t))= g(1) \exp(2 \pi i \phi_g(t))$. Where $\phi_f(0) = \phi_g(0) = 0$ and $\phi_f(1) = \phi_g(1) = n$, where $n$ is the winding number.

Now my first idea was that with $z(t):=\phi_f(t)-\phi_g(t)$ and $g(1)/f(1) = \exp(2 \pi i k)$ for some constant $k$, that $H(t,s) = f(\exp(2 \pi i t)) \cdot \exp(2 \pi i k s) \cdot \exp(2 \pi i s z(t))$ should do it, but then I was wondering: Where exactly did I use that they have the same winding number? So my proof must be wrong. Can andybody here correct it?

Comment: I think that the last factor should be $\exp(2\pi i s z(t))$ to get the interpolation right. Therein also lies the explanation. Unless $z(1)=0=z(0)$ that factor will depend on $s$ and the homotopy breaks down.

Comment: Why is this $s$-factor the explanation, I mean if you look at either $f$ or $g$ $s$ is always $0$ or $1$, so why would the homotopy break down then?

Comment: The homotopy should be a mapping $S^i\times[0,1]\to S^1$. In particular you must have $H(0,s)=H(1,s)$ for all $s\in[0,1]$, because those two values of $t$ correspond to the same point on the circle. If you don't have $z(0)=0=z(1)$ this condition fails.

Comment: As for the correct proof of the statement, it is the same proof as for the fact that $\pi_1(S^1)\cong {\mathbb Z}$. See for instance Massey's "Algebraic Topology" book.